# Rails: Combining Multiple Controller Actions with their own Views into a Single View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, view

I have two different controllers with their own feed(index) actions and I want them to be displayed on a single page (home). The posts and requests models are not similar and hold different types of data (images, video links, strings, etc.).

In my posts controller I have this action. It uses two API actions in the same controller and fills a @post_array with specified record information which then gets displayed in the posts/feed.html.erb view:

```
    def feed
      if user_signed_in?
           post_feed_authenticated
      else
           post_feed_not_authenticated
       end
    end
```

In my requests controller I have a similar action that returns a @request_array with all relevant request records and displays them in requests/feed.html.erb.

```
    def feed
       request_feed
    end
```

The methods the actions call filter all records by location, authentication, and IDs.

I've already created separate views for these actions that work correctly, but I want to combine them so both feeds are shown on the same page (home.html.erb). How do I go about doing this? I've read into using partials but I am not sure if that is applicable here since the data is different.

Edit:
The home controller is:

```
    def home_page
    end
```

The home_page.html.erb currently has buttons to the corresponding post/request feed. I want to put both feeds on the home_page.

Comment: So you have 3 separate controllers: Posts, Requests, Home?

Comment: Yes. The home controller is simple and currently empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it - you want to reuse both the views and the code that populates `@post_array` and `@request_array` in your home view. I see these as two different concerns with different solutions:

- For reusing the views you can use [partials](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials). By having partials for the posts feed and the request feed you could reuse the view in the `home` view.
- And for reusing the way you populate the `@post_array` you could try and place that logic in somewhere where your `HomeController` has access to, ideally your `Post` model (i.e. `Post.feed(current_user, location)`) or a service object. Another, hacky way to do this is by placing these methods in the `ApplicationController`, making them available in all controllers.

Comment: For using the partials, I created a _post_feed.html.erb partial and tried rendering it in the home view. It gave me a NIL error for the post_array, so I am assuming it renders the view but doesn't call the controller function to fill post_array. Any ideas?

Comment: @RoRails that's the second point of my answer - the responsibility to populate the array is yours, meaning you still have to do that explicitly in the controller, just put the code that loads the array somewhere reachable.

Answer (score 0):

You can create instances of each class in the index action of the home controller:

```
@posts = Post.all
@requests = Requests.all
```

Then you have access to all variables and methods in each class.

(Change index from above to whatever you named your home page.)

Comment: I've thought of that, but the feed methods filter all records according to location, authentication, and IDs. Getting them all wouldn't work.

Comment: How are you currently calling the feed methods?

Comment: Inside the feed methods. post_feed_authenticated, post_feed_not_authenticated, and request_feed are API methods within the same corresponding controller. For example requests/feed and requests/request_feed are in the same controller.